# boost::bind and << operator in C++

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I would like to bind the << stream operator:

```
for_each(begin, end, boost::bind(&operator<<, stream, _1));
```

Unfortunately it does not work:

```
Error   1   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<_bi::dm_result<MT::* ,A1>::type,boost::_mfi::dm<M,T>,_bi::list_av_1<A1>::type> boost::bind(M T::* ,A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided c:\source\repository\repository\positions.cpp   90
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead you might try boost.lambda:

```
//using namespace boost::lambda;
for_each(begin, end, stream << _1));
```

The reason of your problem is most probably: how on earth can you expect the compiler / bind to know what you are taking the address of if you say `&operator<<`? (I get a different error simply saying that this is not declared.)

---

If you really want to do it with bind, you'd have to tell it which `operator<<` you want to use, e.g assuming **int** (you'll also need to know, it the operator is overloaded as a member or free function):

```
bind(static_cast<std::ostream& (std::ostream::*)(int)>(&std::ostream::operator<<), ref(std::cout), _1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can probably use [ostream_iterator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ostream_iterator.html) instead:

```
vector<int> V;
// ...
copy(V.begin(), V.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
```